# stdout to multiple files, if stdout to file by default

Tags: stdout, tee

#### 1. Summary

I don't find, what can I do, that text output to multiple files, if by default in CLI program stdout to file.

#### 2. Example

I use [**generate-changelog**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-changelog) package. In this package by default output [**print to file, not to console**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-changelog#usage).

#### 3. Expected behavior

I want to add same output to 2 files:

- `SashaVersion.txt` — file, in which I want to add stdout only one time;
- `CHANGELOG.md` — file, in which I want to add stdout multiple times; this file not must overwrite.

#### 4. Not helped

1. Double using `-f` argument — `changelog -f SashaVersion.txt -f CHANGELOG.md`.
2. [**tee**](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm) command, for example, — `changelog -f | tee SashaVersion.txt CHANGELOG.md`.

Comment: How did `tee` not do what you appear to have wanted it to do?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: possibly, `tee` solve this task, but I don't find, what can I do. In 4.2 example tee create blank file `SashaVersion.txt`, without content. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

> Options:
>
> `-f, --file [file]`      file to write to, defaults to `./CHANGELOG.md`, **use `-` for stdout**

Note that dash, it's quite a common way of marking stdin/stdout.

Based on that text, this would probably work:

```
$ changelog -f - | tee SashaVersion.txt CHANGELOG.md
```

Though it would still print one copy of the output to the terminal, so either of these to inhibit that:

```
$ changelog -f - | tee SashaVersion.txt > CHANGELOG.md
$ changelog -f - | tee SashaVersion.txt CHANGELOG.md > /dev/null
```

If `-f -` doesn't work, try `-f /dev/stdout`.

---

Of course, if you're running zsh, you don't even need `tee`:

```
zsh$ changelog -f - > SashaVersion.txt > CHANGELOG.md
```

In all of those, replace `>` with `>>` if you want the new text to be *appended* to the file as opposed to overwriting the file. If you wanted the output to overwrite `SashaVersion.txt`, and also be appended to `CHANGELOG.md` as well as being written on stdout, you could do:

```
$ changelog -f - | tee SashaVersion.txt | tee -a CHANGELOG.md
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
$ changelog -f - >&1 > SashaVersion.txt >> CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I read npm-changelog documentation, but I thought, that `-` is hyphen or dash, not command line argument.